# C# Access SQL ADD COLUMN

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have a problem with the Query Access. My code is as follows:

```
string query = "ALTER TABLE Student ADD COLUMN Surname MEMO AFTER 'Name'";
```

Why always inserts the column at the end of the table? Is there any method to insert a new column in a specific position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see any reason to add your column to a specific position. You can always use the column order as you want for a select statement for example..

> Why always inserts the column at the end of the table?

Because it is designed like that?

> There is a method to insert a new column in a specific position?

As far as I know, there is no way to do it without rebuilding your table.

From [`ALTER TABLE syntax for changing column order`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739788/alter-table-syntax-for-changing-column-order)

> Today when you use ALTER TABLE ADD to add a column, a new column is
>   always placed as the last column. This is far from often desireable.
>   Often developers and database designers want to keep some logic in a
>   column order, so that related column are close to each other. A
>   standard rule we keep in the system I work with is to always have
>   auditing columns at the end. Furthermore many graphical design tools
>   encourage this kind of design, both bottom-end tools like the Table
>   Designer in SSMS as well as high-end data-modelling tools such as
>   Power Designer.
>
> **Today, if you want to maintain column order you have no choice but to
>   go the long way: create a new version of the table and copy over. It
>   takes time, and if not implemented correctly, things can go very
>   wrong.**